# WCF security: looking for a very specific example

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I'm having a problem where i want to get the users windows login information sent to IIS then from there sent to a WCF service hosted in a console application and then that service uses the credentials to go to a database and retrieve results.

i'm looking for an example on the web that does EXACTLY this but for the life of me can't find one. I can find a million example that 
1. Give general information about WCF, Windows Authentication, Delegation, impersonation etc..
1. Uses the credential to go to a WCF service hosted in IIS and then to the database
2. Uses the credentials to go straight to a WCF service and then to the database

But I can’t an example going first to a regular webpage in IIS, then to a WCF service hosted in a console app and then to the database

Can anyone find this specific scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Can you get current user under IIS? write Login method in WCF and pass that data to WCF service, use sessions, and require that Login should be called first, after all close the session

Comment: i want to use the buit in Windows Authentication/impersonation features of WCF. Looking for an end to end example right now